# could not connect using remote desktop in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

in windows 8.1 recently i noticed that remote desktop connection could not been established during to login error. (i have another PC in internet). but I've tested my brother's laptop to see if my internet pc is remote-able or not but it work's fine( connection is established without any login problems). so i think problem is in my windows 8.1 
could you help me solve this issue.
regards

[image: Remote Desktop Login problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 types of problems with remote desktop:

1. Licensing - this probably doesn't apply to your computer.
2. Network (firewall and so on) - this probably also doesn't.
3. Local security: you have to:

   - allow RDP connections at all
   - allow RDP connections from older version of RDP client (if you need that)
   - add user you want to log in to list of allowed users

How to do it:

- right click on Computer icon, choose Properties
- in System window click Remote setting on left bar
- in System properties/Remote tab click Choose users button
- ensure that your chosen user is added there

(exact names can differ as I translated them from polish version of Windows)

Comment: i cant connect using  my laptop!!!

Comment: i can connect remotely from any other station

Comment: so this is my problem!! and the remote windows works fine!!! and accept any connection. but my laptop windows seems to have problem connecting

Comment: Check your network and firewall settings (you can use PuTTY to try to establish raw connection from your laptop to 3389 port at RDP server). If it works, but RDP still doesn't, then try to enter user name with implicit destination computer name as domain part - eg. my-computer\my-user instead of my-user.

Comment: my-computer\my-user solved my issue +1

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add, at least for Windows 7 and 8.1 ... it had me pull out my hair in despair. The RDP was set, the firewall was set, the network connection was a workgroup with DHCP and up and running through a switch on an ADSL router. It used to work and stopped once I upgraded the network card. What seems to have "unlocked" RDP for me ... shut down both the receiving and sending machines. Shut down, do not restart - I did that half a dozen times and it did nothing. I even reset my ADSL router to force the DHCP to reset everything. Shutting down seems to be critical for Windows to gobble the settings once you switch both computers on again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).