# cannot connect with Remote desktop in windows 8.1 using RDP file

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

I am having difficultie connecting to a remote computer using my dell notebook with windows 8.1

I have connected to this computer many times before using Linux (Remmina and/or KRDC) without any problems but now I have windows 8.1, I won't connect.

this is my error (in Dutch):

!(http://s7.postimg.org/kycwkb0dj/rdp.jpg)

it says: the credentials which are used to connect do not work. Please enter new credentials.

I already read about entering the domain before the username as windows tends to send the domain with the username. I tried that but still without succes.
I have checked on my Linux machine for the domain and I believe it is what is visible on this image:

!(http://s10.postimg.org/nn8w4dhth/IMG_0727.jpg)

I am somewhat irritated that this will not work in windows 8.1 but works without problems in Linux. How can I get this working in windows 8.1?

I am connecting to the shown address with also a specific port: 3391.
so my address for connecting is x.x.x.x:3391.

I have found this similar question: [could not connect using remote desktop in windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/926970/could-not-connect-using-remote-desktop-in-windows-8-1) but I already tried to include the domain.

What else could be the problem?

**edit:**
The RDP file is a file from my wife's work. She works at a primary school and is able to logon on the central computer to do work at home. The rdp file is set with the approriate address and port: just the standard setttings.

**edit 2: added contents from rdp file**"

```
screen mode id:i:2
desktopwidth:i:1152
desktopheight:i:864
session bpp:i:16
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
full address:s:x.x.x.x:3391
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiomode:i:0
redirectdrives:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:0
username:s:1160TS01\d.deroon
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
disable wallpaper:i:1
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
use multimon:i:0
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
```

and 1 off-topic question: I tried to include images as explained using an exclamation mark, but this does not work it seems. I tried to use forum thumbnails, but this also did not work. How can I include thumbnails? (I tried the CTRL+G option, but there I was not able to paste the link to the web location).

Comment: I voted you down for flame regarding the last part - this is a professional community and we try to keep it cool. To explain to you why it is done like this - it is a feature of the RDP stack (SSH actually has something similar): as an admin on the box, I can/should/must choose who has access to the box, regardless of whether they have the right credentials or not (think of a machine on the domain - who has access to it? anyone with a domain user/pass?)

Comment: Getting past the initial communication bump ... you mention an RDP file in the title, but nowhere else. How did you get the RDP file? What are the contents of the RDP file? First thought (if it worked on Linux) - encoding of the file and newlines (that are different in Linux vs Windows). Can you try to connect by doing Win+R -> mstsc -> entering <IP address>:3391 in the box and hit connect? When asked for creds, put in the right creds and see if it works.

Comment: Also, FYI - it is not a good idea to put the raw IP address in the post.

Comment: @cdavid I understand. I will remove the part from the post. I just got carried away by some frustrations. The RDP file is a file from my wife's work. She works at a primary school and is able to logon on the central computer to do work at home. The rdp file is set with the approriate address and port: just the standard setttings. Although I understand what you explain, I still do not get why I might have to add a user on my computer with the same name, just for this. based on the credentials used, the machine should able to know which permissions I have?

Comment: Can you please add the contents of the RDP file (except IP address & password if they are in the file)? Also, did you try to connect manually as I suggested above?

Comment: not yet as I have no had the chance to do so. I will tonight if I have some time. I will also check for the contents of the RDP file. Anything specific you need to know about this file?

Comment: I tried to connect manually as suggested. This was also not succesfull. I have added the contents from the rdp file in my original post.

Comment: What error are you getting when trying to connect manually? If you can not connect manually, then you will not be able to connect via the RDP file.

Comment: I do not get any specific error other than the credentials do not work. I would find it really strange that this worked in winxp, it worked in Linux but that it does not work in win 8.1.

Comment: If the error is that the credentials don't work... then maybe the password changed? I can't think of any other reason why it would complain about the credentials at that point...

Comment: I just checked it on linux and the same username and password worked without any problem. I have returned my laptop and are searching for a new one. When I have received it, I will try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved now. It turns out the needed domain was different.
Somehow, I had 1160TS01 (which I saw on the Linux machine). But the domain had to be S1160.